How to post a payload to an endpoint with cron set up in aws?
I have an endpoint that I need to invoke on a schedule, while invoking the endpoint, I need to post some data as well. example below, can I run this script on a schedule in aws. I know I can set up an eventbridge and set up some cron expression to invoke that, but can I run the script below, or directly run a curl command?
based on the documetation, we can invoke an sns topic as well, but how do I post data when making an HTTP call?
import requests
data = {'somevalue' : 'someothervalue', 
        'onemore': 'anohtervalue'
       }
r = requests.post("http://some.domain.org", data={'number': '12524', 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'})



Perhaps use a Lambda function invoked by EventBridge

EventBridge with scheduled rules and API destinations as a target sounds like the right approach. If you really need to run code, instead of just POST-ing an HTTP request, consider triggering a Lambda function from EventBridge via scheduled rules or EventBridge Scheduler [1]
[1]
Today, EventBridge Scheduler does not support API destinations.
